# Maven: how to build 2 jar with different log4j config from 1 project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a single maven project that has 2 main classes. I want to generate 2 jars with different `log4j2.properties`, I have tried copy-rename-maven-plugin with 2 execution id but it is not working.

```
processA_log4j2.properties
processB_log4j2.properties
src
--com.exampleA
----ProcessA.java
--com.exampleB
----ProcessB.java
--log4j.properties
test
--com.example.test
--log4j.properties
```

```
   <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>test</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>rename-file1</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>src/processB_log4j2.properties</sourceFile>
                            <destinationFile>src/log4j2.properties</destinationFile>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>rename-file2</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>src/processA_log4j2.properties</sourceFile>
                            <destinationFile>src/log4j2.properties</destinationFile>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId><version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly1</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.exampleB.ProcessB</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <finalName>ProcessB</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly2</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.exampleA.ProcessA</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <finalName>ProcessA</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resource1</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../Tmp_output-bin</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>ProcessB.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resource2</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../Tmp_output-bin</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>ProcessA.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
```

Comment: First why do you define different directory setup `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>` ? What is the exact reason? Why do you need a jar with a configuration? In particular log4j ? Why not providing the configuration the log4j from outside..

Comment: @khmarbaise: it is provided by the client so I really don't know why they use the different directory setup, they want to create 2 separate log files for those 2 jar files

Comment: Create different Maven modules is much easier and more clearer than configuration...

Comment: Create a Common module with and a deployment for A and B. Three modules in all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way to do this with maven so I override config in the code for each main class.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#reconfig_from_code